# return of page_address in module and copy it to userspace buffer. is there a way

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, userspace

is there a way to copy/map the return of `page_address` to userspace buffer passed file's `read` function

what I read is

```
 page_address()
```

returns virtial address of the page. and takes pointer to a page which is of kernel's data type

for example I have a function containing this

```
void *rx_buf= page_address(arr_pages[i])
char buf[4094];
memcpy(buf,rx_bu,sizeof(page))
```

can I use memcpy or copy_to_user like

```
memcpy(buf,rx_buf,sizeof(page));
```

or

```
copy_to_user(buf,rx_buf,sizeof(struct page));
```

what I read `copy_to_user` does not a allow this, cause if `buf` is userspace buffer block then it checks the buffer is in the user portion of the memory. also
this also prevents userspace applications from asking the kernel to read/write kernel addresses;

so I like to know is there a way to copy the return of  `page_address` to user space buffer

Comment: If the use of mmap for file is given. How do I know when to check mmap returned `buffer` if I.e. rx_buf` is filled in rx interrupt contexts. Mmap is to map. But how in userspace do I know when to check mapped buffer if data has changed to new data in page it may be page is dma mapped

Comment: You can pass a kernel address to user, but the user-space program can't read or write kernel addresses.  Normally, the user program passes a user buffer address to the kernel, and the kernel can read or write the buffer.

Comment: @stark `Normally, the user program passes a user buffer address to the kernel, and the kernel can read or write` so how can I read and write user buffer in kernel. if kernel has data to write to user buffer which is `void *rx_buf= page_address(arr_pages[i]); copy_to_user(buf,rx_buf,sizeof(struct page));` and in Userspace through `read` or `ioctl` just do `struct ethdr *eth=(struct ethhdr *)buf` is this wrong

Comment: so I am writing kernel data in user buffer and not accessing kernel address in Userspace